# Did Prabhupada believe in Flat earth theory?

Tags: earth, prabhupada

Prabhupada - the ISKCON luminary believed in NASA's fake moon landing and secret government.  From [this](https://lm.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fkrishna.ie%2Fimages%2Fdocs%2Fsailing-to-jambudwipa-20151221-2006.pdf&h=AT0Bdfx2b4DB1V43ZuOeyuKkIaZ3YGI9FxhYJ23CzsxV8bN2n_LaG_A2m-Qchm7DL8argLvh8bQWSoBgImkfI_U21svzXaNeYF4Q2UeAaig5aECfqTvG8-eTPZ4q0gP9fueRIfJLInerXRZzIziZTyijtyJ3So-aXOhEY2ynIFGI4mzT8yZ-ZGTbyvry2JKrrX9OStz7cwerxWUAHixz7diF54GMDZw6EIHAXgo8yDhx3yUO_J6MmhSGqqcLUU8NKv2SN0y2z0ZeFPKqcVMPUD62d7xLsZ5WrRzPngyuBLq4Jxr2Ut9aVt0qdqUvHWaPApFdTG8nO2fP1Ihmkic8IhiEvXDNdWp2enE0oxVdF55Ajkv66Y84ZKvGgnPzlvlxXStu143C6SJstJIyU8KHGZSQhPPGpLRGYo0FofOw26xhtluSXep8AwzMhLgoyg) book by one of the ISKCONite, It seems he believed in flat earth also owing to literalism.

Did he actually believe in flat earth theory?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83554/discussion-on-question-by-rohit-did-prabhupada-believe-in-flat-earth-theory).

Comment: The spherical (Gola) earth immersed in the oceans was saved when brought out  by Vishnu holding it between his nose and tusks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the book which you have linked in your Question, answer depends upon what Bhagvatam says about the shape of the earth (which seems **No**).

On page 147, the author writes:

> My second question to Srila Prabhupäda would be this: why does Srila Prabhupäda use
>   the word bhü-gola to describe the Earth as a round planet? For example in this
>   conversation of 1973:
>
> Prabhupäda:  Yes, world is round. That is fact. Goloka. In Vedic literature it
>   is bhü-gola, jagad-anda. These words are there. We can see also it is
>   round, jagad-anda. The universe is round. And Goloka. Or Bhü-gola. **Bhügola,
>   the earth is round**. So in the Vedic literatures... Therefore their
>   knowledge is also imperfect because they do not refer to the Vedic
>   literatures. It is already there. **Bhü-gola. Bhü means the earth; gola means
>   round**. It is already there. And the geography's called, according to
>   Sanskrit, it is called Bhü-gola. Long, long ago, before Galileo. So if the
>   state is blind, he does not see whether he's talking right or wrong, then 
>   havi candra raja gobi candra mantri (?). What can be done? That is going
>   on. (Morning Walk, **Dec 9, 1973**, Los Angeles)

Prabhupäda's last statement about this topic in the book is:

> Prabhupäda: **Take the version of Bhägavatam.**
>
> (Discussions about Bhü-maëòala, **July 5 1977**, Våndävana )

The word Bhü-gola is found in Bhägavatam which is explained in below articles/blogs by other ISKCONites and in related post.

---

Articles/Blogs by other ISKCONites which discard flat earth theory:

- [The failure of flat earth fanaticism](https://www.facebook.com/VedicCosmology/photos/the-failure-of-flat-earth-fanaticismby-rajasekhara-das-brahmachari-das-acbsprefu/1571676289806964/)
- [Whose Version Should You Believe? Shrila Prabhupada's Round Earth Globe VERSUS Mayesvara's Flat Earth Pancake](http://www.harekrsna.com/sun/editorials/03-16/editorials13740.htm)
- [Vedic Evidence - Understanding the Earth realm we are on in relation to Bhu-mandala](https://iskcondesiretree.com/m/blogpost?id=2103886%3ABlogPost%3A2554845)

---

Related Post(s)

[What is the shape of Earth according to Hindu scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12365/what-is-the-shape-of-earth-according-to-hindu-scriptures)

Comment: Continue reading. Somewhere he says otherwise. He changed his views frequently (expected). if you could somehow tell what was his final conclusion? The conclusion with he died?

Comment: @Rohit. Updated the answer..

Comment: Okay thanks. But to say yes or no, You would have to prove what Bhagvatam says about the earth - flat or globe?

Comment: @Rohit.  A have alreade mentioned that.."The word Bhü-gola is found in Bhägavatam." ... Also I have linked another post which have verse from Bhägavatam...

Comment: The term Bhugol doesn't imply oblate spheroid shape of the earth. It could mean disc like round also.  Couldn't it?

Comment: That's upto translations, commentaries...The related post has the verse from Bhägavatam, clarification can be asked there or may be another Q can be asked..but I think it's not in the scope of this Q...  @Rohit.

Comment: Here few  similar articles  on the views of prabhupada , I think  they are their official blogs. https://iskcondesiretree.com/m/blogpost?id=2103886%3ABlogPost%3A2554845 and http://www.harekrsna.com/sun/editorials/03-16/editorials13740.htm

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Thanks! I shall add them in the answer...

Comment: @YDS, By 'round' could he mean flat circle instead of sphere? Like he says the universe is round as in an egg and the earth is round as in a sphere? Could he have used two different meanings of the word round?

Answer (score 1):

Following is Śrīla Prabhupāda letter to one of His disiples where He clearly says that it appears flat but it is round.

Letter to: Madhava
--
Vrindaban
3 October, 1976

My dear Madhava,
Please accept my blessings. I am in due receipt of your letter dated 22nd Sept. 1976 and have noted the contents. REGARDING DETAILS OF THE UNIVERSE, BE SATISFIED BY READING ONLY BHAGAVATAM. WHAT IS THE USE OF READING OTHER BOOKS--you are not going there. Some portion of the earth is flat. When you stand in any place you see flat, so for us to some extent it appears flat, BUT IT IS ROUND.
Simply keep faith that whatever we describe, that is a fact. After all, we are an insignificant creature in the universe, so whether you take the modern scientists or Sukadeva Goswami, it is inconceivable. It is best to keep faith in Sukadeva Goswami, because actually our only business is to go back to home, back to Godhead. So whether Sukadeva Goswami or the modern scientists are right or wrong, it is nothing interesting to us. We want to go back to home, back to Godhead—yanti mad-yajino'pi mam.

I hope this meets you in good health.

Your ever well-wisher,
A.C. Bhaktivedanta Swami