# Bhagvatam and planet Earth

Tags: bhagavata-purana, earth, cosmology

In the cosmological section of bhagvatam (canto 5 i think) is there a mention about,

Earth being flat ?

Earth centered system (geo-centric theory) ?

Comment: @AkshayKumarS everything is eternal. This is not a place for counter questions. Please visit our chat room for such things.

Comment: Related: [Did Prabhupada believe in Flat earth theory?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29174)