# What causes mass or weight? Is there any relation between mass and energy?

Tags: scripture, vedas

Gradually scientists become against to the formula "E=MC2" and General Relativity.In Vedic point of view,is "mass and energy is interchangeable" truth?
In the Srimad Bhavatam, Bumandara is not glove but flat. That means there is no graviti. Then what cause the mass? The chariot of Yudhishthira maharaja floated in the air. What makes weight of the molecules?

Comment: i heard in one of srivaishnava discourse by swami thiiru velukudi krishna its interaction of jiva with prakruthi that makes jiva to gain linga deha.. such that sattva, rajas and tamas. its like interaction of higgs boson with matter theory where it gains mass

Comment: the word bhumandala eytomological derived bhughola.. ghola is sphere hindu philosopher never consider that physical earth is flat.. for eons of years and they never consider earth is the center of universe.. go to any temple in india navaragha is proof of that with sun at the center..

Comment: brindharanya upanishad says role of vayu in different elements weight.. which was proved by the experiment.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyeF-_QPSbk

Comment: for flat earth see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29190/12304 and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12365/12304

Comment: Dear Prasanna R, thank you for your answer.  I'll have to take that into consideration．

Comment: Dear YDS, thank you for your answer.  I'll have to take that into consideration．

Comment: What? Scientists become against formulas? Who told you that? If that were true this would be worth a nobel prize.

Comment: @ Wikash  You can read many Anti-Relativity treatises, articles, and introductions of books.  https://www.gsjournal.net/   And you go to GSJ Physics.Forum.   There is an famous article titled "Relativity raised to status of a relision".  And many other.